# Explicit calculation of derivatives in Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, differential, frechet-derivative

I am trying to understand if there is an explicit way to differentiate in a Banach space. I am not a mathematician, so don't be harsh!

(In finite dimensional theory, this is easy;  $Df:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is just the Jacobian of $f$.)

Say I have the Banach space $C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$  and a countable basis such that $u = \Sigma \kappa ^iX_i $.

1. I want the derivative of $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, say at $0$. Is it correct to assume:

   $\gamma(t) = \Sigma \kappa^i(t)X_i$ $\Rightarrow$ $\dot\gamma(0) = \Sigma \dot{\kappa}^i(0)X_i$ ??
2. What if the map is $\gamma : C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$  ?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You'll have a linear map $D\gamma(t):\Bbb R \to C^1([0,1],\Bbb R)$, which by linearity will be determined by the value $D\gamma(t)(1)$. This is $\gamma'(t)\in C^1([0,1],\Bbb R)$, computed in the usual way. E.g.: if $\gamma(t)(s) = ts+s\cos t$, then $\gamma'(t)(s) = s-s\sin t$.

Comment: @IvoTerek Thank a lot ! One more question: What if the map is $\gamma : C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$  ?

Comment: Then it's much more complicated, and one would probably need to know the expression for $\gamma$. In the previous example we used very strongly that the domain had dimension $1$.